# How to test apps wirelessly in Xcode or Android Studio?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, bluetooth

What's the fastest and most effective way to test applications via bluetooth or Wi-Fi rather than a standard USB connection in Xcode and Android Studio?

I could transfer the APK file to Google Drive and then test it, however I'm looking for a much faster method which will also work for Xcode.

Will the live debugging data show up fast enough or will there be a lag between the workstation and test device as data is transferred between them?

Comment: For android studio there are multiple wifi debugging apps but that require your phone to be rooted

Comment: upload the apk or ipa file on https://www.diawi.com/ , then they will give you the url of the app. With that url, you can download the app.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode's Help search for "Pair a wireless device with Xcode".